# center element when pressed in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

i really how to do a thing wich is probably easy..

I've a ScrollView with some button in it.
That's how i create all my button in the scrollview.

```
var buttonList = [UIButton]()

func createButton() {
    let imageArray = fillImageArray()
    var lastButtonWidth: CGFloat = 0


    for index in 0..<6 {
        let frame1 = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - 27.5) + CGFloat(index * 70), y: 0, width: 55, height: 55 )
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
        button.setImage(imageArray[index], forState: .Normal)
        button.tag = index
        button.addTarget(parentViewController, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(button)
        lastButtonWidth = frame1.origin.x
        buttonList.append(button)
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(lastButtonWidth + 55, 0)
}
```

I want when i press one of my button to center him and positioning correctly the other buttons.

example : 
[image]

If i press on 5 i want this result :

[image]

the button 5 is moved to the center.

Comment: You want to move the origin.x of your scrollview? Why? That would move your scrollview off the side of the view controller.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to create a higher level of clarity since I can't understand what you want from this question.

Comment: add an example, i hope it ll be more explicit

Comment: If you get the button index like if you click you will get index 5 decrease the index by 2 that is 3 get the button in that index and set the content offset of the scroll view as that buttons origin

Answer (score 7):

Now what I would suggest using is the scroll view method `scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect, animated: Bool)`. This will move the scroll view to make a certain part of your content visible.

To create the CGRect you could do something like this:

```
let scrollWidth = scrollView.frame.width
let scrollHeight = scrollView.frame.height

let desiredXCoor = button.frame.origin.x - ((scrollWidth / 2) - (button.frame.width / 2) )

let rect = CGRect(x: desiredXCoor, y: 0, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight)

scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
```

My math may be a bit off, but the essence is that you use the size of the scrollView and the UIButton to create a CGRect for the scroll view to move to. This means when a button is clicked, you could use an implementation like this:

```
func myMethod() {
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton){

    let scrollWidth = scrollView.frame.width
    let scrollHeight = scrollView.frame.height

    let desiredXCoor = sender.frame.origin.x - ((scrollWidth / 2) - (sender.frame.width / 2) )

    let rect = CGRect(x: desiredXCoor, y: 0, width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight)

    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)

}
```

If adjusted properly to your project, this should allow you to do what you have outlined.

Comment: Nice and simple logic of what you did. Thanks for sharing Benjamin!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this would help you.

In button action method write below code.

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {

        for view in self.scrollView.subviews {

            if view.isKindOfClass(UIButton) && view.tag == sender.tag  {

                let xCenter = max(0, (view.center.x - self.scrollView.frame.width/2))

                self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(xCenter, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
                break;
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the button touched to be placed in the center,so there is a easy solution, you can use the button's center.x - scrollview.width / 2 as the offsetX to construct the contentOffset and take two boundary situation into consideration:offsetx < 0 and offsetx + scrollview.width > scroll.contentSize.width

Answer (score -2):

Ok i just found by myself.

```
let centerScrollView = scrollView.frame.size.height * 2

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: sender.frame.origin.x - centerScrollView, y: sender.frame.origin.y)
        }, completion: nil)
```

and it's perfectly center. Thx everyone.